# Asp.net Gridview Fixed Header in Ajax Popup Window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I need some help with a Asp.net Gridview.  My users need to click a button and have an Ajax Modal Popup window display with a Gridview that has Fixed Headers.  I have tried this many times but no success.  I have been able to use Java to make the headers fixed in a Gridview, but it does not work when displaying in a Ajax modal popup window.  The header row duplicates on the Gridview.  Again, thank everyone for the help.

Can anyone post some code using Asp.net/C#/Ajax.

```
    function BindControlEvents() {
  /*Code to copy the gridview header with style*/
  var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true);
  /*Code to remove first ror which is header row*/
  $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
  $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
  /* Here Set Width of each th from gridview to new table th */
  $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width()).toString() + "px");
            });

        //Initial bind
        $(document).ready(function () {
            BindControlEvents();
        });

        //Re-bind for callbacks
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
            BindControlEvents();
        }); 

            $("#controlHead").append(gridHeader);
            $('#controlHead').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('#controlHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);

        };
```

Comment: can you post your `GridView` code, at least?

Comment: I have added the java code above that I am using

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on why you have all that. What should it accomplish? Can you clarify what you mean by _fixed_, as well? Fixed text, size, or...

Comment: My gridview header row needs to be fixed, meaning that when I scroll the grid the header column stays visible.  I have this working in a page, but if I add the gridview to an Ajax popup it does not work.